# Creating a button with pure css

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a button like this:
[image]
This needs to be done in pure css.

I tried to do, nothing happened, it does not work correctly:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 165px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4b3529 21%, #4c2e1a 100%);
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: normal;
border-left: 2px solid #e5ccaf;
border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffd400,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #ffd400;
```

[image: enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhY8Q.png)]  
How can I do that?!

Comment: Hey, it's tough to see precisely what you are looking for from the images. Is it the yellowish borders you want or the gradient effect on the button's background? Maybe you can give the source of the original button. Also you may need to show some HTML, since copying your code gave me the result you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
button {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: x-large;
            padding: 0.6rem 2rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            overflow: hidden;
            color: #fff;
            background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4b3529 21%, #4c2e1a 100%);
            border:0;
            border-radius: .3rem;
            position: relative;
            border-top: 2px solid hsl(24, 49%, 15%);
            border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(24, 49%, 15%);
        }
        button::after,button::before{
            content: '';
            height: 100%;
            width: .15rem;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffd400, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) ;
        }
        button::before{
            left: 0;
        }
        button::after{
            right: 0;
        }
```

```html
<button>
        Pure Css</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### You can add the CSS properties inside a class. Then add the class to an HTML element with `text-decoration: none;` property as follows:

```css
.pure_css_button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 165px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4b3529 21%, #4c2e1a 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-left: 2px solid #e5ccaf;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffd400, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffd400;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="pure_css_button">
Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible using body::after content "text" and style it